# Get NetworkCredential detail on wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a REST based WCF service.  If the client passes login detail through NetworkCredential like :-

```
   WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
   webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("slash", "slash");
```

then how can I get these NetworkCredential details in WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OperationContext

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity
```

or

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity
```

Comment: is "slash" your windows account?